# How to create a event bridge rule via cloudformation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, amazon-sagemaker, aws-event-bridge

I created an EventBridge rule via the console in AWS. The sample event pattern (see below). I want to create this rule via CloudFormation and specify a SNS Topic as the target for this rule.
Are there any examples on how to do this in CloudFormation?

```
"source": ["aws.sagemaker"],
"detail-type": ["SageMaker Training Job State Change"],
"detail": { 
  "TrainingJobStatus": ["Completed"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS CloudFormation documentation is pretty good on how to declare the different resources and its properties. AWS EventBridge has different resource types, the one that would do what you need is "AWS::Events::Rule", for more information about this resource type please refer to the link below.

A brief example from the documentation (please refer to the link for a detailed explanation):

```
Type: AWS::Events::Rule
Properties:
  Description: String
  EventBusName: String
  EventPattern: Json
  Name: String
  RoleArn: String
  ScheduleExpression: String
  State: String
  Targets: 
    - Target
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html